# Gear S2: How to make the DUID appear in Tizen IDE

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm trying to get the DUID of a Gear S2 in the Tizen IDE. I open the properties window and in the Info tab I can see the Device Name but the DUID is not to be seen. Anybody has an idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that when the tizen-sdk is newly installed, one needs to reboot the machine before the DUID is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

tizen IDE use sdb so you can use sdb kill-server and restart IDE.

sdb is placed in `<tizen sdk root>/tools/sdb`

refer it [SDB commands](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.devtools/html/common_tools/smart_dev_bridge.htm#command)

Answer (score 0):

From CLI :

```
sdb shell /opt/etc/duid-gadget
```

Reference:

- [https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/SDK#error_75_:_SIGNATURE_INVALID_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID](https://web.archive.org/web/20170324183306/https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/SDK#error_75_:_SIGNATURE_INVALID_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID)